# I want use only text in input when submit button is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I need help with pattern. I want to use only letters and space. How I can do it?
For example John Smith. Any help is appreciated.

```
<TextField
          id="name"
          label="Name"
          name="name"
          type="text"
          placeholder="John Smith"
          pattern="/[A-Za-z]/{4,16}"
          title="Name must contain letters and at least 4 characters."
          required
        />
```

Comment: space is `\s`, you can change the regex to include as that, I hope it is helpful

Comment: @LaaouatniAnas /[A-Za-z\s]/{4,16} like this?

Comment: yes but the {4,16} need to be before the /... something like this `/[a-zA-Z\s]{4,16}/`

Comment: @LaaouatniAnas It's not letting me submit any text. I did the way you showed me.

Comment: I tested now, you don't need to use `/` in pattern attribute. if you are writing regex in javascript then yes, but here isn't needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```css
input:valid   {   outline: 3px solid green;   }
input:invalid {   outline: 3px solid red  ;   }

/* just for demo purposes, you don't need this css */
```

```html
<input type="text" pattern="[a-zA-Z\s]{4,16}">
```